# how to let git hub pages link to other .md pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I cnamed to my git hub pages. It displayed README.md as default home page.

Now I want to add some hyperlinks to other .md files(such as **/blog/list.md**). But web browsers can only identify .md files as downloadable files. So web browsers will not display .md files as web pages.

how to solve this problem?

In fact, I can put some HTML pages that hyperlinks to. But Markdown page saves a great amount of time at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write in Markdown and server as regular HTML content, so try to use static site generator like `Jekyll` providing by GitHub Pages.

You can find instructions at [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-the-jekyll-theme-chooser/), then [add more Markdown pages](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-the-jekyll-theme-chooser/#add-more-pages-to-your-site) and `Jekyll` will silently translate `another-page.md` to `another-page.html` for you.